# FireFox versus FireFox Developer

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

This url works fine in FireFox (Latest Version) but does not in FireFox Developer (Latest Version):

http://domain.site.org/JavaScriptSite/ggov.html?city=Minnetonka&dept=Police&extent=[-93.45,44.93]

FF Dev did not like the JSON.parse([-93.45,44.93]). 
What does everyone do when it works on one browser but not another?  Ugh!

Is there a proper way to fix this? Any sites or docs talk about this? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse([-93.45,44.93])` is invalid. `parse` takes a `string` argument, not an array.
 Your code should be `JSON.parse("[-93.45,44.93]")` if anything.

This is not related to browser choice though..

Comment: Thank you.
The browser choice is my confusion.
Same code works in one and not the other.

Comment: @kanderson if this helped please mark the question as solved.